# Apache Rewrite sends to previous directory, local index.php not read

Tags: apache2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't solve a problem I have with (seemingly) Rewrites in Apache2.

It's a migration from server P3 (where everything works) to server P10. The config files are the same, as well as the directory tree ans the permissions (I compared but might have missed something).

I have enabled the rewrite logs in Apache config, maximum log level (debug) but with no luck. I've been searching for 2 days now, almost non stop, but I've got to work on other projects.

***The problem is this one:***

When I access this site:

```
https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
```

**The server does not give me the index page in this directory, but the one in the previous directory:**

```
https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/
```

However, when I type the full location of the page, it works perfectly:

```
https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/index.php
```

*An important fact:
We usually access this website through a VPN. At the exit of the VPN, the packets are directed to P3 (normal routing)
However, for the sake of the test, instead of modifying the domain name, I just capture the packet coming from my IP address and redirect them to the new server P10.*

***Please help!
Thank you in advance! :-)***

**The Rewrites are found in 3 locations:**
(see the logs at the end)

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-acme-ssl.conf
/home/team/fp/sandbox/stats/wheels
/home/team/fp/sandbox/stats/
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-acme-ssl.conf**

```
(...)
  DocumentRoot /home/www-ssl/null
(...)
  RewriteMap vhost     txt:/etc/apache2/vhosts-maps/www-ssl.map
(...)
  # Make sure we have a host header
  RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} !^$

  # Lowercase the hostname
  RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}|NONE}  ^(.+)$

  # Lookup the hostname in map file and remember it only if path is valid
  RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$

  # Finally we map the URL to its document root location
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/$1 [E=VHOST:${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}},L]

  # Handle other cases

  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.acme.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**/home/team/fp/sandbox/stats/wheels/.htaccess**

```
(...)
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/[a-z]+\/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/index.php [L]
```

**/home/team/fp/sandbox/stats/.htaccess**

```
(...)
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/i-?thing(\.(html|php))?\/monitoring [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/ithing-monitoring/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/i-?thing(\.(html|php))?\/dashboard [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/ithing-dashboard/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/[a-z]+\/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/index.php [L]
```

**LOGS**

```
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.663415 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 15243] [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server p10.infra.acme.com:443)
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.665360 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15243] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2139): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername sandbox.acme.com found
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.665581 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15243] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2139): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername sandbox.acme.com found
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.665621 2018] [core:debug] [pid 15243] protocol.c(2257): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server p10.infra.acme.com
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.677192 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 15245] [client 10.19.1.9:53748] AH01964: Connection to child 5 established (server p10.infra.acme.com:443)
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.678050 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15245] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2139): [client 10.19.1.9:53748] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername sandbox.acme.com found
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.678170 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15245] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2139): [client 10.19.1.9:53748] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername sandbox.acme.com found
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.678203 2018] [core:debug] [pid 15245] protocol.c(2257): [client 10.19.1.9:53748] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server p10.infra.acme.com
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.716218 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15243] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2067): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.716682 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15243] ssl_engine_kernel.c(377): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 0 (server p10.infra.acme.com:443)
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.716831 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.716856 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] applying pattern '^/(.*)$' to uri '/fp/stats/wheels/'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.716906 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='!^$' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.716991 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717043 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='^(.+)$' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717092 2018] [rewrite:trace6] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] cache lookup FAILED, forcing new map lookup
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717146 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] map lookup OK: map=vhost[txt] key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717176 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/' pattern='^(/.*)$' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717187 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] rewrite '/fp/stats/wheels/' -> '/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//fp/stats/wheels/'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717199 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717207 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] setting env variable 'VHOST' to 'sandbox.acme.com'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717217 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] local path result: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.717243 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] go-ahead with /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//fp/stats/wheels/ [OK]
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719507 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 10.19.1.0/24: granted
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719546 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: granted
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719555 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719580 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/ ->
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719589 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri ''
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719623 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] RewriteCond: input='/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719638 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] RewriteCond: input='/fp/stats/wheels/' pattern='^(.*)\\/[a-z]+\\/?$' [NC] => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719661 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] rewrite '' -> '/fp/stats/index.php'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719671 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] trying to replace prefix /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/ with /
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719680 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] trying to replace context docroot /home/www-ssl/null with context prefix
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.719687 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b520a0/initial] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/wheels/] internal redirect with /fp/stats/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720290 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] init rewrite engine with requested uri /fp/stats/index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720323 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] applying pattern '^/(.*)$' to uri '/fp/stats/index.php'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720339 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='!^$' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720350 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720359 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='^(.+)$' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720377 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] cache lookup OK: map=vhost[txt] key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720386 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] RewriteCond: input='/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/' pattern='^(/.*)$' => matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720394 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] rewrite '/fp/stats/index.php' -> '/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//fp/stats/index.php'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720404 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720431 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'VHOST' to 'sandbox.acme.com'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720441 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] local path result: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//fp/stats/index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720465 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] go-ahead with /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//fp/stats/index.php [OK]
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720548 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 10.19.1.0/24: granted
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720560 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720588 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720597 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720610 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] RewriteCond: input='/fp/stats/index.php' pattern='^(.*)\\/i-?thing(\\.(html|php))?\\/monitoring' [NC] => not-matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720618 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720626 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720642 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] RewriteCond: input='/fp/stats/index.php' pattern='^(.*)\\/i-?thing(\\.(html|php))?\\/dashboard' [NC] => not-matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720650 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720658 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720674 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] RewriteCond: input='/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.720682 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b3f7b8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/] pass through /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/fp/stats/index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.724203 2018] [:error] [pid 15243] [client 10.19.1.9:53747] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: REQUEST_FILENAME in /home/team/fp/sandbox/stats/index.php on line 29
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.725057 2018] [deflate:debug] [pid 15243] mod_deflate.c(853): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 5493 to 1609 : URL /fp/stats/index.php
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.733301 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15245] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2067): [client 10.19.1.9:53748] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837084 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 15243] ssl_engine_kernel.c(377): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH02034: Subsequent (No.2) HTTPS request received for child 0 (server p10.infra.acme.com:443), referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837180 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837194 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] applying pattern '^/(.*)$' to uri '/favicon.ico', referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837214 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='!^$' => matched, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837228 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837241 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='^(.+)$' => matched, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837271 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] cache lookup OK: map=vhost[txt] key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837282 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/' pattern='^(/.*)$' => matched, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837291 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] rewrite '/favicon.ico' -> '/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//favicon.ico', referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837313 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837322 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] setting env variable 'VHOST' to 'sandbox.acme.com', referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837331 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] local path result: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//favicon.ico, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837344 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b540a0/initial] go-ahead with /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//favicon.ico [OK], referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837813 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of Require env ehs_vpn: denied, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837842 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 10.19.1.0/24: granted, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.837850 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838028 2018] [core:info] [pid 15243] [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/favicon.ico, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838095 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] init rewrite engine with requested uri /error.pub.php, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838112 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] applying pattern '^/(.*)$' to uri '/error.pub.php', referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838127 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='!^$' => matched, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838138 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838150 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] RewriteCond: input='sandbox.acme.com' pattern='^(.+)$' => matched, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838169 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] cache lookup OK: map=vhost[txt] key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838185 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] RewriteCond: input='/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/' pattern='^(/.*)$' => matched, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838194 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] rewrite '/error.pub.php' -> '/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//error.pub.php', referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838207 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] map lookup OK: map=lowercase key=sandbox.acme.com -> val=sandbox.acme.com, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838216 2018] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'VHOST' to 'sandbox.acme.com', referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838239 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] local path result: /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//error.pub.php, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838252 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15243] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] 10.19.1.9 - - [sandbox.acme.com/sid#7f5412beb638][rid#7f5412b49a28/initial/redir#1] go-ahead with /home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox//error.pub.php [OK], referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838309 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838329 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15243] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.19.1.9:53747] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
[Sat Aug 04 17:23:57.838394 2018] [:error] [pid 15243] [client 10.19.1.9:53747] script '/home/www-ssl/dev/sandbox/error.pub.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://sandbox.acme.com/fp/stats/wheels/
```